# How Bash can delete by use wildcard and with exceptions

Tags: bash, search

How Bash can delete by use wildcard and with exceptions e.g. all .BAR deletions below except FOO.BAR

```
$ ls

BOO.BAR
MOO.BAR
COO.BAR
FOO.BAR
JOO.BAR
NOO.BAR
ZOO.BAR
BOO.BAZ
MOO.BAZ
COO.BAZ
JOO.BAZ
FOO.BAZ
NOO.BAZ
ZOO.BAZ
```

tried:

```
$ shopt -s extglob globstar
$ rm *.BAR !(FOO.BAR)
```

not work, it wiped all! Help!

Comment: `*.BAR` matches all files with a `.BAR` suffix (including `FOO.BAR`), except ones whose names begin with dot, so `rm` will delete all of them.  `!(FOO.BAR)` matches all files except `FOO.BAR`, so `rm` will delete all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
shopt -s extglob
rm -- !(FOO).BAR
```

- The  `--` after `rm` is to prevent files with names beginning with a hyphen (e.g. `-MOO.BAR`) being treated as options to `rm`.
- This will not delete files whose names begin with a dot (e.g. `.MOO.BAR`).  Add the `dotglob` option to `shopt -s` if you want to delete such files.

Comment: haven't done a try...     

will explain each command working mechanism ?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use, for this case:

```bash
rm *.BAZ [A-EG-Z]OO.BAR
```

In other words, tailor it to what you have. This will need different commands if the file list is different but you should get the general idea.

If you want to get rid of everything while still keeping just one file, you could also save it elsewhere temporarily, then move it back:

```bash
mv FOO.BAR /tmp/save-foo && rm * && mv /tmp/save-foo FOO.BAR
```